# Why is the order of routing commands important in this case?

Tags: networking, routing, linux-networking, iproute2

Why is the result different between this

```
ip tuntap add dev tun1 mode tun
ip link set up tun1
ip route add 1.2.3.4 via 192.168.0.1 dev eth0
ip addr add 10.0.0.1 peer 1.2.3.4 dev tun1
```

and this (last two commands switched place)

```
ip tuntap add dev tun1 mode tun
ip link set up tun1
ip addr add 10.0.0.1 peer 1.2.3.4 dev tun1
ip route add 1.2.3.4 via 192.168.0.1 dev eth0
```

The former block gives a routing table that looks something like this

```
1.2.3.4 via 192.168.0.1 dev eth0
1.2.3.4 dev tun1  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.0.0.1
```

and the latter gives this (and fails with "RTNETLINK answers: File exists")

```
1.2.3.4 dev tun1  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.0.0.1
```

In both cases I have a default route of `default via 192.168.0.1 dev eth0`.

(The question is somewhat related to my VPN setup. I use a VPN service provided by my ISP. The VPN server is configured so that
the public IP of the VPN server is the same as the IP of the server end of the VPN tunnel.)

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that running `ip addr` will create a default gateway automatically, and that this default gateway is conflicting when you run the `ip route` command. Swapping the order of the commands should add the route first, and then the `ip addr` command will see an existing gateway for that network and not bother to configure one.

You can test this by comparing the routing table after running *only* the `ip addr` command. If this command adds two lines to the routing table, then this is the source of the error.

Comment: The default gateway is unaffected (although not listed in the tables above). The `ip addr` command only adds the routing entry `1.2.3.4 dev tun1  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.0.0.1`.

Answer (score 0):

When you have specified the peer address in the command, the route to this peer address through the interface was added into the main routing table. So manually adding of the route to same destination with same metric fails.

When you're bringing up the VPN, you should have specific route to VPN server, otherwise your VPN will break n if the default route will be changed to route all through VPN.

Comment: Sorry, I was a bit unclear. The question is not about the VPN, it actually works perfectly with the first setup. The question is why the two commands do not commute in this case? I agree that the metric is the same but with the first setup it is possible to add a route to the same destination with the same metric.